# Basic question concerning conditional expectation (of a non-mathematician)

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $(X_i)_{i \geq 1}$ and $\tau \geq 1$ be independent random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\mu$ for all $i \geq 1$. Moreover, let $S_k:= \sum_{i=1}^k X_i$.

I want to show that $$\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau}\mid \tau]=\mu \tau.$$

In my solution, it is written that

$$\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau}\mid \tau]=\mathbb{E}[S_k]\mid_{k=\tau} = \mu k \mid_{k=\tau}=\mu \tau.$$

Now I wonder whether the first step is valid for all kind of random variables? Somewhere we probably use independence of the $X_i$ and $\tau$, but I am not sure where. Additionally, we also need that $S_{\tau}$ is integrable - where do we need this?
Would be very nice if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

By independence $\mathbb{E}(X_i | \tau) = \mathbb{E}(X_i) = \mu$, the rest is just linearity of expectation.  Also, if we're being picky we should say $\mathbb{E}(S_\tau | \tau) = \mu \tau$ almost surely, since conditional expectation is only considered unique up to a set of measure zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still a little bit confused about the order in which I have to do these things. 

So: 

$\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau} \mid \tau] = \mathbb{E}[S_{k}]\mid_{k=\tau}$ is valid even without independence assumption, and then applying independence? But then we do not need $\mathbb{E}[X_i \mid \tau ] = \mu$, or do we?

Or is this only valid when independence holds, so
$\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau} \mid \tau]= \sum_{i=1}^{\tau} \mathbb{E}[X_i \mid \tau]=\tau \mu$, but I doubt that this is allowed to do with a random variable. 

So a little hint about the first step would help.. Thank you!

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(S_\tau \mid \tau) = \sum_{i=1}^{\tau} \mathbb{E}(X_i \mid \tau)$ with no assumption at all.  Then since we have independence we can drop the conditioning on $\tau$ and replace each term with $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was not aware of the fact that linearity of expectation also applies for a random number of summands. Thank you a lot!

Comment: So you would say that $\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau} \mid \tau] = \sum_{i=1}^{\tau} \mathbb{E}[X_i \mid \tau] = \sum_{i=1}^{\tau} \mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mathbb{E}[S_{\tau}] = \mathbb{E}[S_k] \mid_{k=\tau} = k \mu \mid_{k=\tau} = \tau \mu$, where the step in the end, where we "replace" $\tau$ by $k$, is also valid without assumption? And where do we need integrability of $S_{\tau}$? and why?

Comment: I'm confused by your step where you end up with $\mathbb{E}(S_\tau \mid \tau) = \mathbb{E}(S_\tau)$.  This is not true.  Just argue as follows: $\mathbb{E} (S_\tau \mid \tau) = \mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^{\tau} X_i \mid \tau) = \sum_{i=1}^{\tau} \mathbb{E}(X_i \mid \tau) = \sum_{i=1}^{\tau} \mathbb{E}(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu = \tau \mu$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This makes somehow sense to me but somehow not. When you can get from $\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau} \mid \tau]=\sum_{i=1}^{\tau} \mathbb{E}[X_i]$, why can't you go back in the same manner to get equality with $\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau}]$ just by again applying linearity of expectation? 

Moreover, why do we need integrability of $S_{\tau}$?

Comment: Because if we were to pull the sum back inside the expectation, we would need to reintroduce the explicit conditioning on $\tau$ (this is because while $X_i$ is independent of $\tau$, $\sum_{i=1}^{\tau} X_i$ obviously is not), otherwise we'd be referring to the *unconditional* expectation of $S_\tau$, which is actually $\mu \mathbb{E}(\tau)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do not completely understand this topic but at least it seems to make somehow sense to me now.

Still the one remaining issue with the integrability. Which equalities would not hold if this sum were not integrable?